# Port 4200 is already in use . But it's not taken

Tags: node.js, angularjs

I'm working on an angular project, so I've reinstalled windows cause I had issues there, and when I installed node js and angular cli when I hit ng serve I get :

Port 4200 is already in use. Use '--port' to specify a different port.

I checked all services with netstat, but couldn't find the 4200 port, I searched all StackOverflow solutions but none of them worked for me, I even reinstalled nodejs and angular, didn't work either, what should I do

Comment: Seems to a possible issue with the windows build, lots of info and suggestions here: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/9519

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue a bit ago, this might help?

#### Resolved in CMD using;

1. netstat -ano | findstr :**portnumber**
2. taskkill /PID **pididentifier** /F

> PID meaning Process Identifier

[image reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zKsVc.jpg)

Comment: An answer that contains no content in the actual answer except for a link is not appropriate for stackoverflow.  Linked content has a habit of disappearing or changing over time rendering the answer useless as a long term reference.  Please put the content for the answer in the actual answer, not just a link.

Comment: @s1n  I already said I tested it, and didn't work, every port I put he shows me that error !

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and fixed it with:

```
sudo lsof -t -i tcp:4200| xargs kill -9
```

```
npm start
```